# How to use RadSideDrawer with Typescript vue class components?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am trying to use external components with Vue Typescript Class Components. I've installed [standard template](https://github.com/nativescript-vue/vue-cli-template) and modified its `<script>` block according to [instruction](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-vue-with-class-components):

```
    import { Vue, Component, Prop } from "vue-property-decorator";

    @Component
    export default class App extends Vue {
        msg: string = "Hello";
    }
```

But I am getting an error: `No known component for element RadSideDrawer`.

I also tried to include `RadSideDrawer` to `@Component` options with no success:

```
    import { Vue, Component, Prop } from "vue-property-decorator";
    const RadSideDrawer = require('nativescript-ui-sidedrawer').RadSideDrawer;

    @Component({
        components: {
            RadSideDrawer,
        }
    })
    export default class App extends Vue {
        msg: string = "Hello";
    }
```

All my component code is [here](https://gist.github.com/DenisNP/5b1e4251773be9e1503d39e198aa3130). I didn't modify any other parts of the template, so I have this lines in `main.ts`:

```
Vue.registerElement(
    'RadSideDrawer',
    () => require('nativescript-ui-sidedrawer').RadSideDrawer,
);
```

But it doesn't work. How to use RadSideDrawer with class components?

Comment: It works on my end, if you still have issues please share a sample repo where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: I confirm that vue-class-component conflicts with RadSideDrawer. I was not able to make it work with it upgrading all packages to their latest versions nor importing `Vue` from `nativescript-vue` rather than `vue-property-decorator`. If you come up with a solution share it please.

Comment: I probably found a way to make it work, but run into another issue: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/8065

Answer (score 0):

```
//main.ts
...
import RadSideDrawer from 'nativescript-ui-sidedrawer/vue'
Vue.use(RadSideDrawer)
...

//mycomponent.vue
<template>
  <Page>
    <RadSideDrawer ref="drawer">
      <StackLayout ~drawerContent class="sideStackLayout">
        <StackLayout class="sideTitleStackLayout">
          <Label text="Navigation Menu"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <Label
          text="Close Drawer"
          color="lightgray"
          padding="10"
          style="horizontal-align: center"
          @tap="onCloseDrawerTap"
        ></Label>
      </StackLayout>
      <StackLayout ~mainContent>
        <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
          <Button
            text="OPEN DRAWER"
            @tap="onOpenDrawerTap()"
            class="drawerContentButton"
          ></Button>
        </StackLayout>
      </StackLayout>
    </RadSideDrawer>
  </Page>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue, Component } from 'vue-property-decorator'
@Component({ name: 'Drawer' })
export default class Drawer extends Vue {

  private onOpenDrawerTap () {
    const ref = this.$refs.drawer as any
    ref.showDrawer()
  }
  private onCloseDrawerTap () {
    const ref = this.$refs.drawer as any
    ref.closeDrawer()
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you mind editing your answer to include some additional explanation? What is your approach, and how does it address the OP’s problem?

Comment: I just answered that question: "How to use RadSideDrawer with class components?"